# latest changes not showing on Netlify after deployment

Tags: reactjs, deployment

This is my first time deploying a react js app to Netlify and I'm facing some issues.
every time I try to push new commits to GitHub Netlify automatically deploys it but the changes don't seem to take effect for some reason.

Here's the deployment log:

```
2:03:20 PM: Waiting for other deploys from your team to complete
2:03:41 PM: Build ready to start
2:03:43 PM: build-image version: ca811f47d4c1cbd1812d1eb6ecb0c977e86d1a1d
2:03:43 PM: build-image tag: v3.3.20
2:03:43 PM: buildbot version: be8ecf2af866e16fa4301cc5c14de2ccbbb21cf4
2:03:43 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
2:03:43 PM: Starting to download cache of 114.5MB
2:03:45 PM: Finished downloading cache in 1.515845861s
2:03:45 PM: Starting to extract cache
2:03:50 PM: Finished extracting cache in 5.156934064s
2:03:50 PM: Finished fetching cache in 6.69538965s
2:03:50 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
2:03:50 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
2:03:52 PM: Different publish path detected, going to use the one specified in the Netlify configuration file: 'build' versus 'build/' in the Netlify UI
2:03:52 PM: Starting build script
2:03:52 PM: Installing dependencies
2:03:52 PM: Python version set to 2.7
2:03:52 PM: Started restoring cached node version
2:03:55 PM: Finished restoring cached node version
2:03:55 PM: v12.18.0 is already installed.
2:03:56 PM: Now using node v12.18.0 (npm v6.14.4)
2:03:56 PM: Started restoring cached build plugins
2:03:56 PM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
2:03:56 PM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.1, read from environment
2:03:57 PM: Using ruby version 2.7.1
2:03:57 PM: Using PHP version 5.6
2:03:57 PM: 5.2 is already installed.
2:03:57 PM: Using Swift version 5.2
2:03:57 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
2:03:57 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
2:03:58 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
2:03:58 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
2:03:58 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
2:03:58 PM: go version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
2:03:58 PM: Installing missing commands
2:03:58 PM: Verify run directory
2:03:59 PM: ​
2:03:59 PM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
2:03:59 PM: │        Netlify Build        │
2:03:59 PM: └─────────────────────────────┘
2:03:59 PM: ​
2:03:59 PM: ❯ Version
2:03:59 PM:   @netlify/build 3.0.1
2:03:59 PM: ​
2:03:59 PM: ❯ Flags
2:03:59 PM:   deployId: 5f16bd6759d4ae00096bdb64
2:03:59 PM:   mode: buildbot
2:03:59 PM: ​
2:03:59 PM: ❯ Current directory
2:03:59 PM:   /opt/build/repo
2:03:59 PM: ​
2:03:59 PM: ❯ Config file
2:03:59 PM:   No config file was defined: using default values.
2:03:59 PM: ​
2:03:59 PM: ❯ Context
2:03:59 PM:   production
2:03:59 PM: ​
2:03:59 PM: ┌───────────────────────────────────┐
2:03:59 PM: │ 1. Build command from Netlify app │
2:03:59 PM: └───────────────────────────────────┘
2:03:59 PM: ​
2:03:59 PM: $ npm run
2:03:59 PM: Lifecycle scripts included in cortex_app:
2:03:59 PM:   start
2:03:59 PM:     react-scripts start
2:03:59 PM:   test
2:03:59 PM:     react-scripts test
2:03:59 PM: available via `npm run-script`:
2:03:59 PM:   build
2:03:59 PM:     react-scripts build
2:03:59 PM:   eject
2:03:59 PM:     react-scripts eject
2:03:59 PM: ​
2:03:59 PM: (build.command completed in 303ms)
2:03:59 PM: ​
2:03:59 PM: ┌─────────────────────────────┐
2:03:59 PM: │   Netlify Build Complete    │
2:03:59 PM: └─────────────────────────────┘
2:03:59 PM: ​
2:03:59 PM: (Netlify Build completed in 322ms)
2:03:59 PM: Caching artifacts
2:03:59 PM: Started saving node modules
2:03:59 PM: Finished saving node modules
2:03:59 PM: Started saving build plugins
2:03:59 PM: Finished saving build plugins
2:03:59 PM: Started saving pip cache
2:03:59 PM: Finished saving pip cache
2:03:59 PM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
2:03:59 PM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
2:03:59 PM: Started saving maven dependencies
2:03:59 PM: Finished saving maven dependencies
2:03:59 PM: Started saving boot dependencies
2:03:59 PM: Finished saving boot dependencies
2:03:59 PM: Started saving go dependencies
2:03:59 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
2:03:59 PM: Build script success
2:03:59 PM: Starting to deploy site from 'build'
2:03:59 PM: Creating deploy tree 
2:03:59 PM: Creating deploy upload records
2:03:59 PM: 0 new files to upload
2:03:59 PM: 0 new functions to upload
2:03:59 PM: Starting post processing
2:03:59 PM: Post processing - HTML
2:04:00 PM: Post processing - redirect rules
2:04:00 PM: Post processing - header rules
2:04:00 PM: Post processing done
2:04:00 PM: Site is live
2:04:19 PM: Finished processing build request in 36.032433755s
```

the latest commit is 9421ef1 and the changes are visible on the GitHub repo. so what might be the problem in case somebody else was facing a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your netlify build command is set to `npm run`, that needs to be `npm run build` for Netlify to know how to build your React app into a production site.

You can change that in your [`netlify.toml`](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/#build-settings) or in your [Build Settings](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/get-started/#basic-build-settings) on the Netlify website.